# Getting next day date for specific string format in Google Apps Script (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Good day everyone!
Working on aprojectmI had to start working with Google Spereadsheet interface and faced a problem I cannot quickly overcome due to not working with JavaScripts ever before.
I have a date in specific format as a string

```
var date = "2012-08-09";
```

What I need is to get the next day date as

```
date = "2012-08-10";
```

which should include changing not only the day, but month and year too, if necessary.

I've tried using date format

```
  var datum= new Date(date);
  datum.setDate(datum.getDate() + 1);
  date = datum.toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

but the code appears to fail at writing date to datum variable.
What is the best and quickiest way tosolve this litle problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a parsing problem you may have better luck, splitting out the date and putting the parameters in individually, any errors you get would be useful:-

```
var parts = date.split("-");
var datum = new Date(
  parseInt(parts[0], 10), 
  parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1, 
  parseInt(parts[2], 10));
```

There is no built in formatting function for the JavaScript Date object, I'm not sure if the google apps api is any different though. To perform the last line of your code you may either need to write your own functions to extract the data from the JavaScript date object and format it, hint you will also need to write a zerofill function if you want to ensure two digits in your date and month parts of the output.

```
var formatted = datum.getFullYear() + "-" + 
  zerofill(datum.getMonth() + 1, 2) + "-" + 
  zerofill(datum.getDate(), 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!
There are now error logs but result are wrong
After var datum= new Date(date); datum is 1/1/1970 4:00:00
After datum.setDate(datum.getDate() + 1); datum is 1/1/1970 4:00:00
After date = datum.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'); date is Invalid date

Comment: I solved my problem basing on your tips, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem when you tag a question 'Javascript' and when you are actually using Google Apps Script is that you get nice answers from people that do not know some special functions available in GAS.

GAS is based on Javascript but Javascript is not GAS... *if you see what I mean ;-)*

That said, there is actually [a "special" function to format date string](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#formatDate) and I'll show it in the following code.

But there is also another point that could put you into trouble  : if you don't mention hours in your date object there is a risk to shift one day if you live in a country that uses daylight savings.  This issue has been discussed quite often on this forum and elsewhere so I won't give all the details but it's a good idea to take this into account when you play with date objects.  In the code below I extract a `tz` (time zone) string from the date object we have just created to know if it's in summer or in winter time, then I use this `tz` string as a parameter in the `Utilities.formatDate()` method . This guarantees an exact result in every situations.

Here is (finally) the test code :
*(use the logger to see results. script editor>view>logs)*

```
function test(){
  date = "2012-08-9";
  var parts = date.split('-')
  var datum = new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2],0,0,0,0);// set hours, min, sec & milliSec to 0
  var tz = new Date(datum).toString().substr(25,8);// get the tz string
  Logger.log(datum+'    in TimeZone '+tz)
  datum.setDate(datum.getDate() + 1);// add 1 day
  var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(datum,tz,'yyyy-MMM-dd');// show result like you want, see doc for details
  Logger.log(dateString);// the day after !
  }
```

Logger results :

```
Thu Aug 09 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)  in TimeZone GMT+0200
2012-Aug-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a format string to toString works in .NET, and it may work in Java, however this doesn't work in Javascript.
Try the following,

```
var date = "2012-08-09";
var datum = new Date(date);
datum.setDate(datum.getDate() + 1);
date = datum.getFullYear() + "-" + (datum.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + datum.getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in http://jsfiddle.net/ It works.....

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function foo(){
            var date = "2012-08-09";
            var datum = new Date(date);
            datum.setDate(datum.getDate() + 1);
            date = datum.getFullYear() + "-" + (datum.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + datum.getDate();       
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="foo()">
    <p id=demo></p>
</body>
</html>​
```